# How do I start creating Firefox plugins?

Tags: c++, firefox

hi
  I want to create firefox plugin with the help of c++.
  I am using Unix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this reference from Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Plugins).

Comment: To add to the above: There's no 'basic code' since, by definition, each plugin is rather different.

Comment: There are a few plugin samples which might help someone get started.